# Laravel 4.1 Password::validator method custom validations

Tags: php, validation, authentication, laravel, passwords

I am trying to add some validations while using Password::reset and am stuck.

The whole process works out of the box for sending the reminder and resetting the password, but trying to incorporate the code on the docs example is confusing me.

Here is my basic code from the generated controller:

```
public function postReset()
{
    $credentials = Input::only(
        'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
    );

    $response = Password::reset($credentials, function($user, $password)
    {

        $user->password = Hash::make($password);

        $user->save();
    });

    switch ($response)
    {
        case Password::INVALID_PASSWORD:
        case Password::INVALID_TOKEN:
        case Password::INVALID_USER:
            return Redirect::back()->with('error', Lang::get($response));

        case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
            return Redirect::to('/#/login');
    }
}
```

The docs suggest using this method to add additional validations:

```
Password::validator(function($credentials)
{
    return strlen($credentials['password']) >= 8;
});
```

I can add this in and of course it will return false if the first password is too short, but I am not sure where to go from there and looking at the source isn't enlightening me on this one.

Does anyone have any advice or sample code using this method to add length and strong pwd validations? Don't see anything when searching and the docs don't seem to offer much more that I have typed here.

Docs: http://laravel.com/docs/security#password-reminders-and-reset (Be sure to choose docs version 4.1 as they differ from the default 4.0)

Comment: Turns out this WAS working, I just didn't understand how. See this: https://laracasts.com/forum/606-password-reset-validation-with-4-1

Comment: Link dead. Updated link - https://laracasts.com/forum/?p=606-password-reset-validation-with-4-1